# how to set a cmake variable to a URL of a target

Tags: cmake

In my cmake I have several libraries which build inside the source tree.

I have also other projects which are built OUT-OF-TREE. These projects use the same libraries I am building inside my source tree.

The problem is that they use  cmake variables instead of target names. To be able to build the code out-of-tree I should set myself those variables.

I cannot use 'find_library' as the libs have not been build yet.

Is there a way to set a cmake variable name with the url of a target?

Comment: You might want to look into [`ExternalProject_Add`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

Comment: Hi. I was using 'add_subdirectory' which can work with out-of-tree sources provided you set a build directory (second argument). Intention was to use the original CMakeLists.txt